# PHP SOAP with HTTPS webservice and .PEM client certificate

Tags: php, web-services, soap, certificate, soapheader

How to create PHP SOAP with HTTPS webservice and .PEM client certificate ?

When i did that i received the follow errors:

> array(2) { [0]=> string(38) "testeResponse teste(teste $parameters)" [1]=> string(38) "testeResponse teste(teste $parameters)" }
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [wsse:InvalidSecurity] SOAP header missing in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\SOAP\index.php:47 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('teste', Array) #1 D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\SOAP\index.php(47): SoapClient->teste(Array) #2 {main} thrown in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\SOAP\index.php on line 47

The code:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'local_cert'  => $localCert, 
     'passphrase' => $passphrase, 
     'style'      => SOAP_DOCUMENT, 
     'use'        => SOAP_LITERAL, 
     'exceptions' => true, 
     'trace'      => true)
);
$something = $client->teste(array());
echo $something->testeResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning is not about the PEM certificate or SSL. It is simply:

> SOAP header missing

You find [`SOAPHeader` in the PHP manual](http://php.net/class.soapheader). There are some usage examples and user contributed notes in the PHP manual and also here on this website, too. For example:

```
$auth = array(
    'UserName' => 'USERNAME',
    'Password' => 'PASSWORD',
    'SystemId' => array('_'=> 'DATA', 'Param' => 'PARAM'),
);
$header = new SoapHeader('NAMESPACE','Auth',$auth,false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Let me know if you run into problems.